# ROR as server side,how to write post method to get data from client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, post

Want to fetch data from client side,by using an action create,how to fetch data by using post method in create function,My point is how i can get data from client side using create function by post method

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully created."
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
      format.json{ render :json => @post, :only=> :content, :location => @post }
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error"
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)
      format.json{ render :json => @post, :status => :created }
    end
  end
end

def create_a_post
  content = JSON.parse request.body.read
  @post = Post.new[:content]
  @post.save
end
```

My code is correct or wrong to fetch data from client side

any one pls solve my pblm

Answer (score 0):

i have problems understanding your english, but i think that i got your question.

so, as far as i understand, you want to send data via a post-request from the client/browser to your rails app.

when you defined `Post` as a resource, than this is usually done via the create action in your PostsController.

you need to be a little carefull with the names though. there is a difference between `resources :posts` or `resource :post` and PostsController and PostController.

make sure that you read the guides about this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

i have no clue what you are trying to do with that `create_a_post` method. is that supposed to be a helpermethod in the controller?

it's also pretty odd that you are paginating your results in the create method. the usual pattern is to create something and then redirect back to the index action.

Comment: actually dude,my client side is android apps,and my server side is only ruby on rails,i want to get data from client side part by using post method in def create function

Comment: "i want to get data from client side" means what exactly? you want to call a client from your ROR application? or you are sending data via post from your android app? you are too unspecific about what should be happening.

Comment: i am sending post from android app to ror,right now i want to fetch that data in ror@phoet

Comment: sounds reasonable. so what exactly is the problem? do you get an error ?

Comment: i want to get data from client side to server side

Comment: yeah, so what? post that data from client to server!

Comment: from client side i post,i want how to fetch in server side alone@phoet    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828967/fetching-data-in-server-sideror-from-client-sideandroid?noredirect=1#comment24268031_16828967 see this question there i mention both server and client side code also